# Annotationchanged event in pdftron Xamarin forms

Tags: pdftron

I have to listen AnnotationModified event as shown below. But not sure on how/when because CurentPdfViewCtrlFragment is null.

Am using pdftron.PDF.Controls.DocumentView2 as given in this sample https://github.com/PDFTron/xamarin-forms-sample

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use *MPdfViewCtrlTabHostFragment.CurrentPdfViewCtrlFragment* not *base.Viewer.CurrentPdfViewCtrlFragment*

Following code change works fine

```
mDocumentView.MPdfViewCtrlTabHostFragment.CurrentPdfViewCtrlFragment.ToolManager.AnnotationsModified += ToolManager_AnnotationsModified
```

Comment: As Andrew pointed out I have actually subscribed to TabDocumentLoaded event and using that I have subscribed to AnnotationModifed event as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

You should override the `OnTabDocumentLoadedEvent` to ensure that the fragment is not null

https://www.pdftron.com/api/xamarinandroid/tools/api/pdftron.PDF.Controls.DocumentView2.html#pdftron_PDF_Controls_DocumentView2_OnTabDocumentLoaded_System_String_